# Register C# WPF application as a protocol handler

Tags: c#, wpf, protocols, handler

Summary:

**Objective is to configure Windows to open my app when tel: links are clicked**

- It's a new WPF app
- Not required to use a particular installer, publishing, or deployment approach
- Able to use any C# libraries that would simplify the job.

Details:

Using a VS Deployment project or the "Publish" option in VS doesn't result in my app being listed as an option for opening tel: links.

As this will need to work for our users without manual installation steps, I am looking for the "right" approach which can (hopefully!) be implemented in the app and/or its installer.  To confirm that it's registered properly, I'd be able to go through steps 1-4 in the linked image & see my app in the list of available apps.

[tel link configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQxJE.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58113343/1136211